# A for loop to create methods, or some equivalent?

Tags: c#, for-loop, methods, runtime

I'm working on a project and I'm in a situation where the administrator needs to accept new users into the system. I've got a form that only admins can access, which shows a list of all the waiting applicants. I've found out how to create buttons at run time and how to add an event handler for the click event, but the handler requires a method by the same name to run.

Obviously I can't just put code for a method inside a for loop, unless I'm mistaken. How would I give the program the ability to support an potentially infinite amount of applicants?

```
void AcceptUsersAdminLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    //FOR LOOP - To be finished. Will read an xml file to find out # to loop.
    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(newButtonClick);
    newButton.Text = "Accept";
    Panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);

}

private void newButtonClick (Object sender, System.EventArgs e){

}
```

This works, but as I've said, only for one button. As relatively painless as it would be to copy the method and append it's name with a number a hundred times, I'd prefer to find a way with support for more.

Comment: I was going to do that, but the only automatic grid formatting I could find was DataGrids and I decided to display them in more of a manual grid. Its fine for what I need it for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use that same method for all of your buttons!  The `sender` parameter will tell you which button is the source, simply cast it to a button.  You can store an ID of some sort in the `.Tag()` property of the button so you know who you are working with (when you create them, assign it).

```
private void newButtonClick (Object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    // ... do something with "btn" in here ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Answer to the titular question: **You don't create methods in a loop**. You will occasionally create anonymous methods in a loop, but save that for later :).

To do what you want though: When you generate these buttons, they should *all* be pointing to the same event handler. The logic you want to run is the same, but the data is different.

How you get the data to the function is not trivial, one (hackish) way to do it is to store the related object (or its index) in the `Tag` property of the button, which you can then retrieve via the `sender` argument of the event handler.

Comment: To the downvoter, what is wrong with this answer? Its effectively the same as the later answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure most people stopped reading after the first line... which is really misleading in his case, "You don't but here is how"...

Comment: @chancea I can change it, but that really is the answer. You don't dynamically create methods (most of the time). There is clearly confusion on the part of the OP on how methods are supposed to work.

Comment: Then explain better on what you "Don't do" because until I read the whole answer I was unsure of what you "Don't do".  I see now you were referring to the OP's Title, but if you just fully read the OP's question it is very misleading from the title.  Which the solution is something you "Can Do"

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I can upvote now :) But I was not the guy who downvoted so I can't help you there

Comment: I answered slowly with my phone while chewing on tacos and was surprised to see I got points when there was another answer posted already by the time I finished.  I don't see any thing wrong with your answer.

Comment: @chancea I figured that; just always like to get feedback when someone has a problem with something I post. The different response to the *other* post was especially confusing. No worries, it happens :)